# Cloth simulation render issue (mesh breaks every 20 frames of the simulation)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation, collision

I am currently experiencing this annoying cycles render issue where every 20 or so frames in my 3120 frame cloth simulation, these weird streaks appear on my mesh:

[image: cycles render with grey streaks through mesh]

Below arre my physics and modifiers settings for the object:

[image: my cloth physics tab settings]
[image]

Self collisions is on and I have a good quality step (15 quality step value and 7 for collision quality value). The issue seems to be caused by the sub div and solidify modifiers I have after the cloth modifier but im simply just following what ive seen a lot of other tutorials do. For the most part, most frames are perfectly fine, it seems to be the frames where a lot of collisions are occurring like in the screenshot above when this issue happens. Ive rebaked multiple times now but the issue is still there, only that the frames that the issue occurs on is different.

I know that if I was to bake my cloth sim with the subdiv and solidfy modifier above the cloth modifier it would fix the problem but ive already attempted that and I calculated that the bake would take 3 days to complete. Here's what it looks like without the streaks:[image]

Please help! Also let me know if I should be providing any more info, this is my first post to this site

Comment: Every time I've filed a bug report on simulations because of similar issues the devs have closed it saying precisely that you have to do the bake because it is a documented workaround and they're not going to fix the simulation bugs.

That means, unfortunately, that your only solution is to do the bake, because you're experiencing a bug in the simulation.